Astro ssr and intl are not working on vercel as getting they are working in local
Context - Trying to add a country based redirection to specific language page using middlewares
Problems - The locales are included and working in the local
But things are not working and locales are not getting sent in the vercel hosting
I have used include files directives as well in the config.
The config file
import {{ defineConfig }} from 'astro/config';
import vercel from '@astrojs/vercel/serverless';

export default defineConfig({{
  output: 'server',
  adapter: vercel({{
    includeFiles: ['./src/locales/**/*'],
  }}),
}});

error
ENOENT: no such file or directory, realpath '/vercel/path0/src/locales/**/*'

And if I am using edgeMiddleware then getting the error
The package "node:os" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.

I try all the things mentioned above
